# Pyspark: Replacing value in a column by searching a dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm a newbie in PySpark.

I have a Spark `DataFrame` `df` that has a column 'device_type'.

I want to replace every value that is in "Tablet" or "Phone" to "Phone", and replace "PC" to "Desktop".

In Python I can do the following,

```
deviceDict = {'Tablet':'Mobile','Phone':'Mobile','PC':'Desktop'}
df['device_type'] = df['device_type'].replace(deviceDict,inplace=False)
```

How can I achieve this using PySpark? Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use either `na.replace`:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('Tablet', ), ('Phone', ),  ('PC', ), ('Other', ), (None, )
], ["device_type"])

df.na.replace(deviceDict, 1).show()
```

```
+-----------+
|device_type|
+-----------+
|     Mobile|
|     Mobile|
|    Desktop|
|      Other|
|       null|
+-----------+
```

or map literal:

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit

mapping = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*deviceDict.items())])


df.select(mapping[df['device_type']].alias('device_type'))
```

```
+-----------+
|device_type|
+-----------+
|     Mobile|
|     Mobile|
|    Desktop|
|       null|
|       null|
+-----------+
```

Please note that the latter solution will convert values not present in the mapping to `NULL`. If this is not a desired behavior you can add `coalesce`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce


df.select(
    coalesce(mapping[df['device_type']], df['device_type']).alias('device_type')
)
```

```
+-----------+
|device_type|
+-----------+
|     Mobile|
|     Mobile|
|    Desktop|
|      Other|
|       null|
+-----------+
```

Comment: Greetings. Even though it is more than a year later: I want to use the mapping approach with pyspark 2.1. However, in contrast to the example, when my table contains a "NULL" entry I get the error : "Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6564.collectToPython.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use null as map key!". Am i misunderstanding this or can you give a hint on where the problem has its source? Thanks

Answer (score 23):

After a lot of searching and alternatives I think that the simplest way to replace using a python dict is with pyspark dataframe method `replace`:

```py
deviceDict = {'Tablet':'Mobile','Phone':'Mobile','PC':'Desktop'}
df_replace = df.replace(deviceDict,subset=['device_type'])
```

This will replace all values with the dict, you can get the same results using  `df.na.replace()` if you pass a dict argument combined with a subset argument. It's not clear enough on his [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace) because if you search the function `replace` you will get two references, one inside of `pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace` and the other one in side of `pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.replace`, but the sample code of both reference use `df.na.replace` so it is not clear you can actually use `df.replace`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a little helper function, inspired by the R `recode` function, that abstracts the previous answers. As a bonus, it adds the option for a default value.

```py
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit, when, isnull
from pyspark.sql.column import Column

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('Tablet', ), ('Phone', ),  ('PC', ), ('Other', ), (None, )
], ["device_type"])

deviceDict = {'Tablet':'Mobile','Phone':'Mobile','PC':'Desktop'}

df.show()
+-----------+
|device_type|
+-----------+
|     Tablet|
|      Phone|
|         PC|
|      Other|
|       null|
+-----------+
```

Here is the definition of `recode`.

```py
def recode(col_name, map_dict, default=None):
    if not isinstance(col_name, Column): # Allows either column name string or column instance to be passed
        col_name = col(col_name)
    mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*map_dict.items())])
    if default is None:
        return  mapping_expr.getItem(col_name)
    else:
        return when(~isnull(mapping_expr.getItem(col_name)), mapping_expr.getItem(col_name)).otherwise(default)
```

Creating a column without a default gives `null`/`None` in all unmatched values.

```py
df.withColumn("device_type", recode('device_type', deviceDict)).show()

+-----------+
|device_type|
+-----------+
|     Mobile|
|     Mobile|
|    Desktop|
|       null|
|       null|
+-----------+
```

On the other hand, specifying a value for `default` replaces all unmatched values with this default.

```py
df.withColumn("device_type", recode('device_type', deviceDict, default='Other')).show()

+-----------+
|device_type|
+-----------+
|     Mobile|
|     Mobile|
|    Desktop|
|      Other|
|      Other|
+-----------+
```

Comment: how can you avoid hard coding 'device_type'? @yardsale8

Comment: Since `device_type` is a column name, I am not sure you want to abstract that out.  If you did, you could put the expression in a function that had the `df`, column name, and translation dict as arguments.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using `df.withColumn` too:

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit

deviceDict = {'Tablet':'Mobile','Phone':'Mobile','PC':'Desktop'}

mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*deviceDict.items())])

df = df.withColumn('device_type', mapping_expr[df['dvice_type']])
df.show()
```

Comment: How to do it in scala language ?

Comment: @mytabi I think there is no `create_map` and `lit` for scala and spark. However `match` and `case` in scala can be an alternative solution to achieve the same result.

Comment: @AliAzG is there a way to Remove those rows from a pyspark dataframe whose entries from a column [of the pyspark] are not present in a dictionary's list of keys?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do it is to apply a `udf` on your dataframe :

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col , udf

    deviceDict = {'Tablet':'Mobile','Phone':'Mobile','PC':'Desktop'}
    map_func = udf(lambda row : deviceDict.get(row,row))
    df = df.withColumn("device_type", map_func(col("device_type")))
```

Comment: thanks..there is a option in case the value not match with the column and set None?

Comment: A proper way to do it :

    def mapping_func(x,deviceDict):
        try:
            return deviceDict.get(x,x)
        except:
            return None
    
    map_func = udf(lambda row : mapping_func(row))
    
    df = df.withColumn("device_type", map_func(col("device_type")))

Answer (score 2):

Another way of solving this is using `CASE WHEN` in traditional sql but using `f-strings` and using the python dictionary along with `.join` for automatically generating the `CASE WHEN` statement:

```
column = 'device_type' #column to replace

e = f"""CASE {' '.join([f"WHEN {column}='{k}' THEN '{v}'" 
             for k,v in deviceDict.items()])} ELSE {column} END"""

df.withColumn(column,F.expr(e)).show()

+-----------+
|device_type|
+-----------+
|     Mobile|
|     Mobile|
|    Desktop|
|      Other|
|       null|
+-----------+
```

---

**Note:** *if you want to return `NULL` where the keys doesnot match, just change `ELSE {column} END` to `ELSE NULL END` in the case statement for variable `e`*

```
column = 'device_type' #column to replace

e = f"""CASE {' '.join([f"WHEN {column}='{k}' THEN '{v}'" 
             for k,v in deviceDict.items()])} ELSE NULL END"""

df.withColumn('New_Col',F.expr(e)).show()

+-----------+-------+
|device_type|New_Col|
+-----------+-------+
|     Tablet| Mobile|
|      Phone| Mobile|
|         PC|Desktop|
|      Other|   null|
|       null|   null|
+-----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I have found is:

`df.replace(list(deviceDict.keys()), list(deviceDict.values()), 'device_type')`