# Get value from Pyspark Column and compare it to a Python dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a pyspark dataframe that I want to add another column to using the value from the Section_1 column and find its corresponding value in a python dictionary. So basically use the value from the Section_1 cell as the key and then fill in the value from the python dictionary in the new column like below.

**Original dataframe**

| DataId | ObjId | Name | Object | Section_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| My data | Data name | Object name | rd.111 | rd.123 |

Python Dictionary

```
object_map= {'rd.123' : 'rd.567'}
```

Where section 1 has a value of rd.123 and I will search in the dictionary for the key 'rd.123' and want to return that value of rd.567 and place that in the new column

**Desired DataFrame**

| DataId | ObjId | Name | Object | Section_1 | Section_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| My data | Data name | Object name | rd.111 | rd.123 | rd.567 |

Right now I got this error with my current code and I dont really know what I did wrong as I am not to familiar with pyspark

> There is an incorrect call to a Column object in your code. Please
> review your code.

Here is my code that I am currently using where object_map is the python dictionary.

```
test_df = output.withColumn('Section_2', object_map.get(output.Section_1.collect()))
```

Comment: you could try `output.Section_1.collect()[0][0]`, but this only works if your dataframe has only 1 row

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but i have multiple rows.

Comment: try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52015818)?

Comment: That might have done it but I found that there is a null values and gave this error

Comment: Cannot use null as map key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52015818) with added null handling):

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit, when

object_map = {'rd.123': 'rd.567'}
mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*object_map.items())])

df1 = df.filter(df['Section_1'].isNull()).withColumn('Section_2', F.lit(None))

df2 = df.filter(df['Section_1'].isNotNull()).withColumn(
    'Section_2', 
    when(
        df['Section_1'].isNotNull(), 
        mapping_expr[df['Section_1']]
    )
)

result = df1.unionAll(df2)
```

Comment: I think this is really close, but still gives me the issue of null values

Comment: That was my original issue and saw it at the top of your code. Im not very use to pyspark and the imports

Comment: If you have null entries, you cannot map that to anything using the dictionary.

Comment: I do have null entries in the dataframe. I see so could I use an if else like in python to map this?

Comment: Use `when` in Spark, not if/else, just like in my code, which checks that the column is not null.

Comment: So what do you want to be the expected output when section_1 is null entry?

Comment: Null again. That would be fine.

Comment: test_df = output.withColumn('Child_2',when(output['Child_1'].isNotNull(),mapping_expr[output['Child_1']]).otherwise(None))

Comment: Then my code should already do this. The default for otherwise is None.

Comment: I tried that but still gave me an error java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use null as map key.

Comment: could you start from the beginning to ensure that you don't have any old dataframes that contain the old code which does not handle nulls?

Comment: avoid doing `df = df.withColumn(...)`. Use a new variable for each transformed dataframe.

Comment: I redid my code and cleaned it, but still the java null error. should I switch to a different method over a dict like an array or something else?

Comment: It is close but gave me this error Union On Different Number Of Columns

Comment: But i think that actually works I just need to work a little at joining the two dataset, thank you I appreciate it

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for walking me through this. I really appreciate it.