# How to add to my DataFrame new column with data from dictionary?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark

So, let's say I have such dataframe:

| country_code | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 123 |
| UK | 1234 |
| PER | 12345 |

And dictionary:

countries = {
"US" : "United States",
"UK"  : "united Kingdom",
"PER" : "Peru",
}

And what I want to do is compare country codes of DF with keys of dictionary and add one more column to DF with full name of countries using PySpark that will look like this:

| country_name | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| United States | 123 |
| united Kingdom | 1234 |
| Peru | 12345 |

I tried to do this code:

```
df = df.withColumn('country_name', when(col('country_code') != '', countries[df.country_code]).otherwise(col('country_code')))
```

But got this error: typeerror: unhashable type: 'column'.

I also tried to create another Dataframe from my dictionary, then used Join, but it seems too complicated.
Is there any option to do this thing without turning my dictionary into dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below one -

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit, when

object_map = { "USA" : "United States", "UK" : "united Kingdom", "PER" : "Peru", }
mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*object_map.items())])

df1 = dff.filter(dff['country_code'].isNull()).withColumn('country_name', lit(None))

df2 = dff.filter(dff['country_code'].isNotNull()).withColumn(
    'country_name', 
    when(
        dff['country_code'].isNotNull(), 
        mapping_expr[dff['country_code']]
    )
)

result = df1.unionAll(df2)
```

Refer -
[Get value from Pyspark Column and compare it to a Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231153/get-value-from-pyspark-column-and-compare-it-to-a-python-dictionary)

Comment: Hello Priyanka, thank you, this helped a lot!
Used this part of your code:

```
    mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*object_map.items())])

    result = fuel3.filter(fuel3['country_code'].isNotNull()).withColumn(
        'country_name',
        when(
            fuel3['country_code'].isNotNull(),
            mapping_expr[fuel3['country_code']]
        )
    )
```