# Pyspark: Replacing value in a column by searching a dictionary with <NA> values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a situation where I have a dictionary of items in PySpark like this:

```
swap={'A': 0.07677341668184234,
 <NA>: 0.1497896460766734,
 'B': 0.07186667210628232}
```

Note the "pandas.NA" object defined as one of the keys.

I also have a pandas table set up with various values that may or may not be in the "swap" dictionary above:

```
index  column
1      C
2      B
3      <NA>
4      A
```

Per other code I've found on stackoverflow here: [Pyspark: Replacing value in a column by searching a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976237/pyspark-replacing-value-in-a-column-by-searching-a-dictionary), I have been using the following function to swap out the above column:

```
def recode(col_name, map_dict, default=None):
    if not isinstance(col_name, Column): # Allows either column name string or column instance to be passed
        col_name = col(col_name)
    mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*map_dict.items())])
    if default is None:
        return mapping_expr.getItem(col_name)
    else:
        return when(~isnull(mapping_expr.getItem(col_name)), mapping_expr.getItem(col_name)).otherwise(default)
```

and the following command:

```
data=df.withColumn("column", recode('column', swap, default=0))
```

where 'df' would be the example dataframe above. The expected output should be:

```
index  column
1      0
2      0.07186667210628232
3      0.1497896460766734
4      0.07677341668184234
```

However I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NAType' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

This error is caused by the "pandas.NA" object in the "swap" dictionary. How can I get this code to work as expected and stop crashing?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have a partial answer to the question:

```
def recode(col_name, map_dict, default=None):
    if not isinstance(col_name, Column): # Allows either column name string or column instance to be passed
        col_name = col(col_name)

    if pd.NA in map_dict:
        col_name=when(~isnull(col_name), col_name).otherwise(map_dict[pd.NA])
        map_dict.pop(pd.NA)

    mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*map_dict.items())])
    if default is None:
        return mapping_expr.getItem(col_name)
    else:
        return when(~isnull(mapping_expr.getItem(col_name)), mapping_expr.getItem(col_name)).otherwise(default)
```

The three lines starting with "if pd.NA in map_dict:" prevent the crash and will work most of the time, but will fail for some cases of "map_dict", such as:

```
map_dict={'A': 0.07677341668184234,
 <NA>: 'A',
 'B': 0.07186667210628232}
```

This will result in "pandas.NA" values being replaced by "0.07677341668184234" instead of "A" as desired. A more elegant solution would not suffer from this problem.