# How to add a new colum to pyspark datafarme with dictionary values?

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to add a new column to my existing data frame in pyspark. My data frame looks
like as follows. And I was trying with the help of this post
[Pyspark: Replacing value in a column by searching a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976237/pyspark-replacing-value-in-a-column-)
by-searching- a-dictionary

Fruit

Orange
Orange
Apple
Banana
Apple

the code I was tring as like this

```
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 from itertools import chain

 simple_dict = {'Orange': 'OR, 'Apple': 'AP', 'Banana': 'BN'}

 mapping_expr = F.create_map([F.lit(x) for x in F.chain(*simple_dict.items())])

  def addCols(data):
     data = (data.withColumn('Fruit_code', mapping_expr[data['Fruit']]))
     return data
```

Expected output:

> Expected output:

```
Fruit    Fruit_code
Orange   OR
Orange   OR
Apple    AP
Banana   BN
Apple    AP
```

I'm getting below error: I know its because of function F. But I don't know how to fix. Can someone help me ?

```
FILE "/MYPROJECT/DATASETS/DERIVED/OPPORTUNITY_WON.PY", LINE 8, IN <MODULE>
MAPPING_EXPR = CREATE_MAP([LIT(X) FOR X IN CHAIN(*SIMPLE_DICT.ITEMS())])
FILE "/MYPROJECT/DATASETS/DERIVED/OPPORTUNITY_WON.PY", LINE 8, IN <LISTCOMP>
MAPPING_EXPR = CREATE_MAP([LIT(X) FOR X IN CHAIN(*SIMPLE_DICT.ITEMS())])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code snippet to get it working.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from itertools import chain

simple_dict = {'Orange': 'OR', 'Apple': 'AP', 'Banana': 'BN'}

mapping_expr = F.create_map([F.lit(x) for x in chain(*simple_dict.items())])

def addCols(data):
    data = (data.withColumn('Fruit_code', mapping_expr[data['Fruit']]))
    return data

data = spark.createDataFrame([("Orange", ), ("Apple", ), ("Banana", ), ], ("Fruit", ))

new_data = addCols(data)

new_data.show()
```

### Output

```
+------+----------+
| Fruit|Fruit_code|
+------+----------+
|Orange|        OR|
| Apple|        AP|
|Banana|        BN|
+------+----------+
```